# Can't resize partition

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to make my Windows partition bigger so I made my Ubuntu partition 150 GBs smaller. Now when I try to resize my Windows partition it won't go bigger -- it only gives me the option to make it smaller. How do I enlarge my partition?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resize your `/dev/sda2` partition, you have to boot from Ubuntu live disk or gparted live disk.

- Boot from Ubuntu live disk.
- Open gparted partition editor from dash. If gparted is not installed by default then install it by running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted` command on terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T).
- Make sure that all the partitions are unmounted before trying to resize.
- Now right-click on `/dev/sda3` and select resize option. Move the dragger to the extreme right so that  150 GB of unallocated space would comes before `/dev/sda3` partition.
- After that, you can be able to resize your `/dev/sda2` Windows partition.

Comment: Would a gparted live usb work

Comment: sure, go ahead.

Comment: best answer for last 20 articles I had read

Answer (score -3):

You just cant do it without having newly boot and do partition preferable during installation  time . resizing partition may be allowed by some third party software but its going to harm your computer hard-disk. or if you join two partition or devide into two partition may be your system file will be corrupted and you will be unable to browse over windows or ubuntu . neither you can use kde partition manager and kvpm ,this will be avilable in ubuntu software center. or for in case windows you can use many third party software avilable