# Cant extend ubuntu partition after removing windows from dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 16.10

I had a dual boot running on my laptop... I was running windows alongside ubuntu but as for now I don't require windows because most of my space was occupied by windows so i removed it via Gparted..i dont know why but I cant extend my ubuntu partition. I've given it 40gb before and as I deleted the windows os now and trying to extend ubuntu partition but wont let me do that. Please let me know how can I sort this out.

I've attached my partition image below.

[image: Ubuntu partitions]

Comment: You can't resize a partition that's currently mounted. I'd expect it to work if you use a live CD/USB, as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/466073/cant-resize-partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, or gparted Live CD, to manage your partitions. Once there, you'll want to...

## Before you start, backup your important data as these operations could corrupt or loose data!

- right-click on sda7 and choose **move/resize**
- position the mouse pointer into the center of sda7 and **move** sda7 all the way left
- position the mouse pointer on the right-edge of sda7 and **resize** the partition to the right for as large as you wish sda7 to become
- close the **move/resize** window
- click the **Apply** icon
- if sda7 will NOT occupy all of the unallocated space, you'll need to also move sda8

  - right-click on sda8 and choose **swapoff**
  - right-click on sda8 and choose **move/resize**
  - **move** sda8 all the way left
  - close the **move/resize** window
  - click the **Apply** icon
  - right-click on sda8 and choose **swapon**